# Access denied when calling Zurmo's login REST api service

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2

I'm trying to call the login API from Zurmo's CRM but it keeps returning an access denied error.
This is the code I am using, taken from the zurmo.org wiki.

```
public static function zurmoTests()
{
    $username = 'super';
    $password = 'root';

    $headers = array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'ZURMO_AUTH_USERNAME: ' . $username,
        'ZURMO_AUTH_PASSWORD: ' . $password,
        'ZURMO_API_REQUEST_TYPE: REST',
    );
    $response = ApiRestHelper::createApiCall('http://localhost/zurmo/app/index.php/zurmo/api/login', 'POST', $headers);
    return $response;
    $response = json_decode($response, true);

    if ($response['status'] == 'SUCCESS')
    {
        return $response['data'];
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the response I'm receiving.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>ERROR: El URL solicitado no se ha podido conseguir</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      <!--  %l  body :lang(fa) { direction: rtl; font-size: 100%; font-family: Tahoma, Roya, sans-serif; float: right; } :lang(he) { direction: rtl; float: right; }  -->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="titles">
      <h1>ERROR</h1>
      <h2>El URL solicitado no se ha podido conseguir</h2>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="content">
      <p>Se encontró el siguiente error al intentar recuperar la dirección URL: <a href="http://127.0.0.1/zurmo/app/index.php/zurmo/api/login">http://127.0.0.1/zurmo/app/index.php/zurmo/api/login</a></p>
      <blockquote id="error">
        <p><b>Acceso Denegado</b></p>
      </blockquote>
      <p>La configuración de control de acceso evita que su solicitud sea permitida en este momento. Por favor, póngase en contacto con su proveedor de servicios si cree que esto es incorrecto.</p>
      <p>Su administrador del cach&eacute; es <a href="mailto:webmaster%W">webmaster</a>.</p>
      <br>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="footer">
      <p>Generado Sat, 08 Mar 2014 15:29:41 GMT por Proxy_CIREN (squid/2.7.STABLE9)</p>
      <!-- ERR_ACCESS_DENIED -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm calling the api from apigility in an MVC event. My zurmo web root is in /var/www.
Hope someone can help me. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Squid Proxy is stopping  your connections `<!-- ERR_ACCESS_DENIED -->`

Can you:

1 - You should see how you can bypass the proxy of their institution "Proxy_CIREN"

2 - Set your environment to make all requests go through the proxy:
- If you are working in Windows I recommend you see the possibility of installing CPROXY
- If you are working in Linux you can do the following in the console(for example):

```
export http_proxy="http://usuario:contrasenna@proxy.ciren.cu:3128"
```

I hope you ;-)